# Can Windows XP be upgraded to Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8-upgrade

I'm using Windows XP Professional SP3 and want to install Windows 8.1 Pro VL.

If I choose *Update* option while installing, that can move files, settings and applications to Windows 8, so can I install by this option, given that I have Windows XP SP3?

Comment: Do not drasticly edit your question, if you have a new question then ask a separate question

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following you correctly, you want to perform an in-place upgrade of XP to Windows 8.1.

This is not supported.

From [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-vista-xp-tutorial):

> To upgrade to Windows 8.1 from Windows Vista or Windows XP, you'll need to install it from a Windows 8.1 DVD and *perform a clean installation*. **This means you won't be able to keep any files, settings, or programs when you upgrade**.